# Android recent app thumbnail

Tags: android, thumbnails

My app appears incorrectly in most recent apps list on ICS and JB devices.

The thumbnail is cut, distorted, sometimes a screenshot of completely different app appears for my app.

Some activities may not be shown though they are not marked as exclude from recent.

What can be wrong and what should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because it doesn't give enough details. It's hard to see what's wrong from a statement. Try at least to post some code where you think the error may occurs.

Comment: OK. What is required from the app to have its thubmnail shown correctly in most recent apps on ICS and JB? What part of the app code would you like to see?

Comment: You can edit your question to improve it and add more information yourself! :) Just use the "edit" gray link below it. And well, try to show a relevant part of the app, the displaying code maybe, try to locate where you problem arise. You can also post screen shots.