# How to force app to create thumbnail (snapshot) for recent apps list?

Tags: java, android, thumbnails, android-recents

Tester of my app has reported:
"The thumbnail of the app in the Recent apps list is not tuned at all. At me it appears either like a homescreen wallpapers (tolikdru: probably, just transparent rect), or like green background of the app screen, but never as a real snapshot of the app."
So the behaviour is something [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878278/android-recent-app-thumbnail).

My device is with Android 2.0 so I cannot check and debug the issue (thumbnails in Recent apps are since Android 3.0+). So further research was in a "blind mode".

I decided to manually force creation of app thumbnail using onCreateThumbnail() [as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848132/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-thumbnail-of-an-app-in-the-android-task-switcher-l). (To simplify the task for the beginning, I do not catch a real snapshot but take the splashscreen drawable.)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail(Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas thumbCanvas) {
    super.onCreateThumbnail(outBitmap, thumbCanvas);

    //splashscreen drawable to bitmap
    outBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.titel);

    //automatically scale to provided canvas 
    //(is the canvas provided as input ???)
    thumbCanvas.drawBitmap(outBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());

    //is the outBitmap itself scaled to canvas or its copy???
    return true;
}
```

I am not sure if the code above is correct because I cannot test it (see below).

[According to docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas%29) another possible solution may be just a dummy @Override onCreateThumbnail with only super.onCreateThumbnail() inside, since the docs say:

> The default implementation returns fails and does not draw a
>   thumbnail; **this will result in the platform creating its own thumbnail**
>   if needed.

But **the onCreateThumbnail method doesn't fire**, at least on my Android 2. Actually the trick is designed to work on Android 3+.
The same is [reported here (year 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130599/how-to-change-the-snapshot-shown-by-recent-apps-list) [and also here (year 2009)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/J5uBtHzhG8E). In both cases used Android version is not specified.

**So will you please help with the questions:**

1) Will the code above work on Android 3+ devices that using thumbnails in Recent apps list?

2) If nope, is there any other workaround to make the app to generate a correct thumbnail (or arbitrary drawable to my choice)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[This is an issue with the OS](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370). Unfortunately, it just doesn't seem to work. If you don't want people looking at your app from the recents for some reason, you can put

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

As the first line in your onCreate() method of the activity.