# Custom recent history image in Android

Tags: android, recent-screens

Is there a way or workaround to achieve custom image showing in app's recent history ?

I know the android activity already given for such case :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail (Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) {
     // draw custom image here.
    return true;
}
```

**But unfortunately this method is never called.**

So anyone knows how can possibly achieve that ?

> > Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Seems there is a bug. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370 multiple people reported the same issue you are having. What are you trying to achieve?

In case of just hiding sensitive info have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817259/how-to-force-app-to-create-thumbnail-snapshot-for-recent-apps-list

Comment: I already seen that report issue. So no one can able to set custom image on recent history view ?