# How to set thumbnail for Recent Apps screen?

Tags: android, android-recents

My app shows sensitive information that I don't want showing up in the 'Recent Apps' screen so I'd like to change what is shown there, or have it show nothing.

I've seen an answer from a few years ago about using `Activity.onCreateThumbnail()` but it doesn't seem to work. `getWindow().addFlags(FLAG_SECURE)` achieves this but I don't want to prevent users from taking screenshots.

Is there a way I can achieve what I need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32953309/115145

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare but I also need to allow people to take screenshots for reporting bugs - sorry, I should have stated that in the question

Answer (score 0):

I am late to answer but think this can be done easily you need to use onWindowFocusChanged method. Here is how you can define in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    yourViewWhichNeedtobeShowninRecentScreen.setVisibility(hasFocus ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

But there is a catch if you show any dialog or bottom sheet window when window is not focused it will show that recent app view in background which you set in "onWindowFocusChanged" method.