# Make the app content blank in the "recent apps" list

Tags: android, android-layout

When the app is shown in the recents menu, I need to make the content blank, so that screenshots can not be taken.
This flag works

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

and the screen becomes empty white. I need to handle the scenario where the user has selected the dark mode, and so the screen must be empty dark.

What other options can I have other than using this flag?

Comment: check this link if it can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/75463362/2715073

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you do not have control over how the OS displays your app in the overview screen, in terms of the color when `FLAG_SECURE` is used.

Comment: thanks a lot. A question: do you know if enabling/disabling it in onpause/onresume respectively, could cause any issue?

Comment: @gianpaolo: You cannot reliably change the `FLAG_SECURE` setting, last I checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this library on github that solves the problem.

https://github.com/nimblehq/recent-apps-thumbnail-hiding

You can use custom layout for the recent app views.